# How to find JavaScript functions/methods without unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

In our project we have written unit test's for some methods, we are planning to write unit test's for methods and functions which doesn't have test's.

Is there a tool or script to automatically find/list methods and functions without unit test's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after a test coverage tool such as [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/).

Comment: Thanks Alex. Istanbul is amazing!